# Какие прилагательные соответствуют английским stateful и stateless?

Tags: прилагательные, переводы

Перевожу статью с английского на русский, и встретил термины stateless widget и stateful widget. По смыслу очень подходят "виджет без состояния" и "виджет с состоянием", но хотелось бы найти прилагательные, точно передающие смысл.

Сразу приходящие на ум "состоятельный" и "несостоятельный" к этой отрасли не относятся. А подходящие по смыслу синонимы "динамический"/"статический", "изменяемый"/"неизменяемый" отражают перевод других свойств - static/dynamic, mutable/immutable.

"Постоянный"/"непостоянный" звучат тоже, как мне кажется, не очень для данного контекста.

Никто не может подсказать что-либо?

Answer (score 2):

**По смыслу очень подходят "виджет без состояния" и "виджет с состоянием"**

Вот так и переводите. Это достаточно общепринятые (специальные) термины, не нужно придумывать вместо них неизвестные и непонятные другим людям. Иногда используют другие варианты перевода, например: "с сохранением состояния" и, соответственно, "без сохранения", но эти тонкости лучше, наверное, уточнять на специализированных форумах.

Answer (score 0):

Активный виджет/Пассивный виджет (неактивный)?

Comment: Не передает смысл - здесь речь идет о том, сохраняет ли виджет свое первоначальное состояние или же может принимать другие состояния в процессе работы приложения.

Answer (score 0):

В Интернете можно найти такие названия: Stateless and Statefull widgets — виджеты с изменяемыми и неизменяемыми  состояниями. Другой (короткий) вариант: изменяемые и неизменяемые виджеты.

(Виджет с неизменяемым  состоянием не содержит параметры, которые можно менять).

В этой статье рассказано о Stateless объектах в общем плане (почему они дословно называются объектами без состояния, а также что такое состояние объекта):   https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/stateless-i-immutable-java/

Как я понимаю, состояние объекта определяет набор изменяемых параметров.